# Total count of particular document in vespa

Tags: vespa

I have multiple documents in vespa and I want to get total count of documents of particular type of document.How can I get this? Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query for the document type with `/search/?yql=select * from sources * where sddocname contains "<yourdoctype>";` and look at 'totalCount' in the result.

Comment: Thanks so much andreer

Comment: Is it possible to get total number of documents without using search query?

Answer (score 1):

Vespa also exposes this as a regularly updated metric, see https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/metrics.html

It may also be possible to query the index per node using command line tools but these are mostly for debugging and may not be a stable api. You can try vespa-proton-cmd at https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/vespa-cmdline-tools.html

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: Looks like the first link was moved to the https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/metrics.html